# Python dictionaries "no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

New to Python, couldn't seem to locate this answer.  I'm trying to use Dictionaries like hashes or associative arrays from other languages, not sure if that's correct or not.

Right now I'm doing:

```
data['person'] = {'birthday': '01-01-1980'}
```

**Edit: `data` is a `dict` being returned from `json.loads(response.text)`**

This is throwing an `object has no attribute '__getitem__'` error.  Looking this up on SO tells me that I need to be returning a string from my **unicode** method, but these are just plain old dictionaries, nothing special.

Python v2.7.4

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/url/returning/json
Django Version: 1.5.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'Person' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
Exception Location: /path/to/error/file in next_work_item, line 356
Python Executable:  /path/to/project/.venv/bin/python
Python Path:    
['/path/to/project/',
 '/opt/pycharm-3.1.1/helpers/pydev',
 '/path/to/project/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.7.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/path/to/project/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.7.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/path/to/project/',
 '/path/to/project/.venv/lib/python2.7',
 '/path/to/project/.venv/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/path/to/project/.venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/path/to/project/.venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/path/to/project/.venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/path/to/project/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/path/to/project/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/path/to/project/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/path/to/project/sub/project,
 '/path/to/project/sub']
```

Comment: What is `data` before the code you've shown is run? Can you post the full traceback of the exception?

Comment: I hope data looks like `data = {}`.

Comment: It's a dictionary as well.

Comment: No part of the code you've shown should invoke `__getitem__`. Can you show us the actual error message? It probably says something about `__setitem__`, but maybe `data` is some non-dictionary type whose `__setitem__` invokes some object's `__getitem__`.

Comment: What does `type(data)` say?

Comment: @marshall.ward `<type 'dict'>`

Comment: I'm assuming that your one-line example works fine in the shell, but the error occurs in the context of Django, is that correct? Is there any way to check the type of `Patient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-2.7/bin/python

data = {}
data['person'] = {'birthday': '01-01-1980'}
```

...so data is probably not a dict in your case.  An SSCCE might help.